# Limit Points in non-metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

If $(X,T)$ is some topological space, and $S \subset X$, how can we find/prove some $l \in X$ is a limit point of $S$? I understand how we can do this when we have the concept of distance (i.e. limit points in a metric space), but can anyone provide an example using a topology other than the standard metric one on the reals?

Comment: You often use net convergence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore-Smith_convergence , or ultrafilters. Notice that convergence of Riemann sums is an example.

Answer (score 1):

Once case is that of Net Convergence. Informally, if you want to know if an indexed collection $x_{\alpha}$ converges to $x$, you need $\alpha$ to be a directed set  with an ordering on the set $\alpha$, and you ultimately want to have an index $\alpha_0$ so that every element of $x_{\alpha}$ is "eventually" in any neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ when $\alpha>\alpha_0 $ , i.e., if $\alpha_j > \alpha_0 $ , then $x_{ \alpha_j}$ is in the given neighborhood.  See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore-Smith_convergence. Notice that convergence of Riemann sums is such an example, where the ordering is by partition width.

Answer (score 0):

In a topological space what you have is a bunch of open sets, and that's it. In this context, $l$ is a limit point of $S$ if for every neighborhood $U$ containing $l$ there exists $s \in S$ such that $s \in U$. In the case of metric spaces the concept is exactly the same, the only difference is that you work with the topology induced by the metric.